# Bash: Replace strings in file with an array

Tags: arrays, bash, replace

I want to replace strings in a file using a bash array.

e.g. the file example.txt:

```
A: Netherlands
B: Germany
C: United States
A: Netherlands
[Edit #2: In the file are also different strings without the format X:Y]
C, N: United States
```

Now I want to have a bash script to replace the letters (Edit: before the colons) so it becomes

```
A => Amsterdam
B => Berlin
C => Chicago
N => New York
```

So finally I want to have

```
Amsterdam: Netherlands
Berlin: Germany
Chicago: United States
Amsterdam: Netherlands
[Edit #2: In the file are also different strings without the format X:Y]
Chicago, New York: United States
```

And this using a bash script but it won't matter if we include other scripting languages like perl.

Thank you!

Comment: Say you have a line in your input file `A : China`, should it be replaced by `Amsterdam : Chicagoina`? Or dou you only want to replace the latters before the colon?

Comment: It would be better if only the letters before the colon would be replaced. But sometimes there are different letters before one colom, e.g. `A + C`

Comment: Simply to fully understand the question: what if there are multiple letters before the colon? For instance `AC : Germany` replace it into `AmsterdamChicago : Germany`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But it will be used more like that "N, C: United States" => "New York, Chicago: United States"

Comment: @RonGranger: You cannot change the requirements on the go. You should have given you current update as part of the first time post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$source = file("/path/to/input/file.txt");
$lines = count($source);
$town = array();
$town["A"] = "Amsterdam";
$town["B"] = "Berlin";
$town["C"] = "Chicago";
$town["N"] = "New York";
for($i=0;$i < $lines; $i++)
{
  $line = $source[$i];
  if (strpos($line,":"))
  {
    foreach($town as $a => $v)
    {
      $c_town = explode(":",$line);
      $c_town[0] = str_replace($a,$v,$c_town[0]);
      $line = implode(":",$c_town);
    }
  }
  echo $line; # or do what you want with it
}
```

Finally I solved my problem by using an external php script. I know there are better ways because php is not always pre-installed on the operating system but it worked best.
Because the script parses the file line per line don't replace the echo with a write command (e.g. `file_put_contents("/path/to/file",$line,FILE_APPEND);` because it is slow and produces much traffic on your disk. I recommend to cache the output in an array and save it at the end of the script.

Thanks for the answers though, they work in most cases but weren't the solution for my problem because they mostly have problems with different contents in the file.

Comment: for php you could have used strtr

Answer (score 0):

if `A B C` are the only cases:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":";d["A"]="Am..";d["B"]="Berl..";d["C"]="Chica.."}
     {$1=d[$1]}7' file
```

if you have many `A, B, C, ...A1..Ab...Ax...`. I suggest you create a dictionary file in this format (dict.txt):

```
A:Am...
B:Berlin...
C:Cfoo
D:Dbar...
.....
....
Z:Zwhatever
```

Then you can:

```
awk -F':' -v OFS=":" 'NR==FNR{d[$1]:$2;next}{$1=d[$1]}7' dict.txt yourFile
```

Above codes were not tested, but my eye-compiler tells that it should go. ^_*

### update according to the Question change

if there could be CSV in $1, you can first `split()` then get `d[splitedElements]` and concatenate the results. It is minor change, but you want to get hand dirty, I believe.

Comment: `awk: command line:1: NR==FNR{d[$1]:$2;next}{$1=d[$1]}7`
`awk: command line:1:              ^ syntax error`

Is the output (Edit: Of the second option). The ^ at the syntax error points at the colon in `[$1]:$2`

Comment: Okay, for me there are not that much things to replace so I used the single first option now.
Now I have another problem: In the file there are still other things that I don't want to be removed. At  the moment I get an file with empty lines and only the part where something has been replaced is still there.
And additionally multiple replacements as mentioned in the comments from my question are not supported (e.g. "A + C"). Thank you for your help!